# Pycurl install error

Tags: django, python-2.7, pip, easy-install, pycurl

When I am trying to install pycurl using easy_install, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.34', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-     0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1937, in main
with_ei_usage(lambda:
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute- 0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1918, in with_ei_usage
return f()
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute- 0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1941, in <lambda>
distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953,    in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 358, in run
self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 598, in easy_install
return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 628, in install_item
dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 823, in install_eggs
return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1103, in build_and_install
self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1089, in run_setup
run_setup(setup_script, args)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 33, in run_setup
lambda: execfile(
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 81, in run
return func()
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 35, in <lambda>
{'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
File "setup.py", line 568, in <module>
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 179, in run
cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 166, in call_command
self.run_command(cmdname)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 20, in run
self.build()
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 111, in build
self.run_command('build_ext')
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 46, in run
_build_ext.run(self)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 307, in run
customize_compiler(self.compiler)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 170, in customize_compiler
_osx_support.customize_compiler(_config_vars)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 418, in customize_compiler
_find_appropriate_compiler(_config_vars)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.6.2-0/python/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 185,  in _find_appropriate_compiler
if 'llvm-gcc' in data:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Can you guys please guide me in the right direction. I have tried installing it with pip also but no luck, I get the same type of error.

Comment: Which version of pycurl install and you have installed libcurl 7.19.0 or better?

Comment: @Krasimir I just did pip install pycurl and easy_install pycurl. I didn't specify any version. Btw i have python 2.7

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error with pip ... I updated the libcurl and libcurl-devel packages (and curl by dependency) and re-ran pip intall pycurl and it installed.